# Interrupt a thread when an action occurs and then resume it?

Tags: java

I will use a thread object called **TaskThread** to execute certain tasks (TimerTasks actually). All the timer tasks are run by one thread only. The user of my program can interrupt this thread any time they want. When the interrupt occurs, a **method** will run and the **TaskThread** can resume only after that **method** completes.

Is it possible to do this in Java ?

Comment: Interrupting a thread is generally not a good idea. Use [Producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) model instead.

Comment: I would use another thread to perform concurrent tasks.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - yes. My problem does not really need the producer-consumer model. I could use another thread to perform concurrent tasks, besides the one thread which executes all TimerTasks.

Comment: @SayemAhmed - My problem does not need the producer-consumer pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interrupt a thread, but you can have a thread periodically check for a condition, typicslly a boolean flag, then take action.

Make sure the flag is `volatile`.`